# Understanding unitialized objects in Java

Tags: java, class, object, jvm

I'm trying to understand how storing a reference into `Object[]` works in Java. So I generated a `Class` with `ASM` library as follows:

```
public static Class<?> getKlass(){
    String className = "TestClass";
    ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);

    classWriter.visit(V1_8, ACC_PUBLIC, className, null, getInternalName(Object.class), null);

    MethodVisitor mv = classWriter.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC, "m", "()[Ljava/lang/Object;",null, null);
    //ARRAY_SIZE
    mv.visitInsn(ICONST_1);
    mv.visitTypeInsn(ANEWARRAY, getInternalName(Object.class));
    mv.visitInsn(DUP);
    mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
    mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, getInternalName(Object.class));
    mv.visitInsn(AASTORE);  // <--- Here is the problem
    mv.visitInsn(ARETURN);
    mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
    mv.visitEnd();

    return new ByteArrayClassLoader().defineClass(classWriter.toByteArray());
}
```

When I run this code JVM signals with `java.lang.VerifyError` that

```
Type uninitialized 6 (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Object'
```

Adding constructor invokation works as expected

```
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, getInternalName(Object.class));
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, getInternalName(Object.class), "<init>", "()V", false);
mv.visitInsn(AASTORE);
```

Now it works fine. But the behavior is not clear. I expected the uninitialized and initialized objects have the same type. As specified in [***JVMS***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4) we do not have a special uninitialized type. So I expected JVM allows to load the class with uninitialized reference.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an *uninitialized* type, but it only exists in the verifier, resp. in stack map table entries supposed to aid the verifier. Since it is a strict requirement that your method, which contains the `NEW` instruction, must invoke the constructor via `invokespecial` and it must invoke it before using the object, there is no need to model it in the general type system. Once the verifier has made sure that every method initialize objects correctly, you won’t encounter uninitialized objects at inappropriate places.

The [§4.10.1.2. Verification Type System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.2):

> ```
>      Verification type hierarchy:
>
>                                   top
>                       ____________/\____________
>                      /                          \
>                     /                            \
>                  oneWord                       twoWord
>                 /   |   \                     /       \
>                /    |    \                   /         \
>              int  float  reference        long        double
>                           /     \
>                          /       \_____________
>                         /                      \
>                        /                        \
>                 uninitialized                    +------------------+
>                  /         \                     |  Java reference  |
>                 /           \                    |  type hierarchy  |
>      uninitializedThis  uninitialized(Offset)    +------------------+  
>                                                           |
>                                                           |
>                                                          null
> ```

`uninitializedThis` is the type of the `this` reference within a constructor, before the superclass constructor has been called. `uninitialized(Offset)` is the type of an instance created by `NEW` before the constructor has been called. “`Offset`” refers to the instruction offset of the `NEW` instruction within the method’s byte code. This allows to keep track of multiple uninitialized instances that may fly around, e.g. when doing `new Foo(new Bar(new Baz()))` or even `new Foo(new Foo(new Foo()))`. As elaborated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41227342/2711488), tying the uninitialized instance to the creating `NEW` instruction imposes some restrictions on the code structure, e.g. you can not merge uninitialized types of different `NEW` instructions, even if they have the same reference type after invoking the constructor.